# Entity Framework 7 migration not creating tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with my first project using Entity Framework 7 and am connecting to a SQL Server where the Database is already created but there are no tables in it yet. I have created my `DbContext` and created a class, then set a `DbSet<>` inside my context. I ran the commands to enable migrations and create the first migration, then rand the command to update the database. Everything looked to work fine, no errors came up, but when I look at the database only the `EFMigraitonsHistory` table was created. When I look at the class that was created for the initial migration it is essentially blank. What am I doing wrong?

Commands I am running:

```
dnvm install latest -r coreclr
dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
dnx ef database update
```

Context:

```
namespace JobSight.DAL
{
    public class JobSightDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<NavigationMenu> NavigationMenu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Table Class:

```
namespace JobSight.DAL
{
    public class NavigationMenu
    {
        [Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int16 ID { get; set; }

        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ExternalURL { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Int16? ParentID { get; set; }

        public virtual NavigationMenu Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<JobSightDBContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:JobSightDatabase:ConnectionString"]);
                });
    }
```

Class for initial migration (autogenerated by EF):

```
namespace JobSight.WebUI.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
After doing what Poke has suggested this is my new auto-generated migration. The table is still not being created at the database level though.

```
namespace JobSight.WebUI.Migrations
{
    public partial class MyFirstMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "NavigationMenu",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<short>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ActionName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ControllerName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ExternalURL = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ParentID = table.Column<short>(nullable: true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_NavigationMenu", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_NavigationMenu_NavigationMenu_ParentID",
                        column: x => x.ParentID,
                        principalTable: "NavigationMenu",
                        principalColumn: "ID",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable("NavigationMenu");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set up the entity in your database context first. At the very least, you would need to do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationMenu>();
}
```

---

The problem with your migrations was a bit hidden in your project layout. So what you have is a `JobSight.DAL` project that contains the entities and the database context. And then you have a project `JobSight.WebUI` which is the actual ASP project containing the `Startup.cs` with the database setup.

This is causing problems because by default EF will just assume to find everything in the current assembly. So if you are launching the `ef` command from your web project, it will create the migrations in there even if the context is in another project. But when you’re then trying to apply the migration, EF will not find it since it will only look in the context’s project.

So to fix this, you need to create the migrations in the `DAL` project. You can do that by specifying the project when you call the `ef` command:

```
dnx ef migrations add Example -p JobSight.DAL
```

You can verify that this worked by running `dnx ef migrations list` afterwards. This should now return the `Example` migration; previously, that command didn’t return anything: It could not find a migration which is the reason why the `update` command only said `Done` (without applying the migration) and the database wasn’t created. So if you now get the migration there, you can then apply it using:

```
dnx ef database update
```

Note that since the migration is now created in the DAL project, you need to add a reference to `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` there, otherwise the project will not compile. You need to do that before you can run the `list` command above.

Finally, for some more information about this, see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4188).

Comment: I added the override code to my context and now the migration class does have code in it to generate a table but when running the update command it is still not building my table. I have updated the original post with the commands I am running to do this.

Comment: Does the `ef database update` return any output? Are you sure you’re looking at the correct database? Check your connection string to make sure what you’re working with.

Comment: I am sure it is the right DB. I can delete the EFMigrationHistory table and it gets recreated, plus it is the only DB on the server. When I run the `dnx ef database update` command all it does is sit there then says `done`. Do I have to do something special since the DB was already existing just not having any tables?

Comment: You did create a new migration and that migration has a CreateTable call in the `Up` part, right?

Comment: A new migration class was generated for me and it does contain the `CreateTable` command. I will post the new one in OP in just a moment

Comment: Can you try clearing the whole database, removing the `Migrations` folder from your project, and then recreating and applying the migration?

Comment: Just tried that. Called the Migration `Test1` this time. I see the `Test1` migration class made and the history table is added to the DB but not the NavigationMenu table

Comment: Is there any way you can share your whole project so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Sure where would you like me to dump it?

Comment: Maybe on GitHub, or upload a zip somewhere?

Comment: ok give me a few minutes to figure out where to post it. Don't have anywhere setup to share files right now

Comment: this should do it for you https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxA-roBz9DmBdzU5SXZ6dUdnV1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution :)

Comment: thanks for all the help. It is working now. One thing to note, in my DbContext I did not need the `modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationMenu>();` line.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not the answer to the original question, I post my answer here because it might help someone who has a similar problem. My problem was also that the tables were not created, but `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` did create 3 .cs files in the *Migrations* folder. But `dotnet ef database update` only created the MigrationsHistory table and `dotnet ef migrations list` did not return any migrations.

It turned out that the problem was that the **Migrations** folder was excluded from the Visual Studio project. Once I included it again, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I resolved it

1. I deleted my database in SQL
2. I changed the name I used for the previous migration. I changed from "Add-Migration InitialCreate" to "Add-Migration NewName"

Comment: This is not really helpful but this is helpful for those who are working on local databases and testing. Useful answer but not completely.